How to calculate the decrease in strength caused by Edge effects and localized stress?
I am interested in a situation where a pipe has water flowing through it and a metal object is in the pipe, which blocks the pipe but contains holes that allow the water to flow through it. I am interested in the pressures exerted by the flowing water on the material of the object near the edges of these holes.
I know the size of the holes, the distance between holes, the thickness of the material, the water pressure in the pipe, and the flexural, shear, tensile, compressive, and hydrostatic pressure strengths of the material - is there any way that I can calculate (or at least estimate!) these strengths of the material near the edges of the holes as a percentage of the overall given strengths?

I would approach this problem by assuming that the diameter of the holes and the spacing of the hole array (assuming a triangular pattern) is much smaller than the pipe diameter.  In this way, you could look at a unit cell of the array, and determine the flow in the region of one of the holes.
